# Best practices to update a Drupal multisite installation

Tags: php, drupal

im gonna install a drupal multisite behavior: common codebase and one database per site.

The idea is to keep the modules that are used by all the sites in the `/sites/all/modules/` folder, and the themes and modules used just by one sites in it `/sites/example1.com/` folders.

I've read the 10 minutes multisite configuration and all went well with the first try, but now i have some question.

When some of the 'common' modules will be update, i have just to update the `/sites/all/modules/modulename` folder, that's ok, but what to do when the module's update need to update the database too?

I have to login and run the `update.php` for each site, or there is an automated procedure, in order to update all the databases of the sites that are using that module?

I guess that updating the module's scripts but leaving the module's db table untouched will cause some problem.

And how to put all sites in 'off-line' mode while im updating the modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newest version of Drush will run update.php against the site you specify from the command line.

Install Drush and run drush --help to see some of its magic.

http://drupal.org/project/drush

Comment: OMG that's great! i'll give it a look deeper